# IF THEN statement in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm not sure why this code doesn't work in SAS. May someboday help, please?

```
DATA WORK.POLLUTION;
    INPUT State $ County $ City $ Month $ Year $ O3MAX $ Category;
IF O3MAX < 0.054 THEN Category = "Good";
    ELSE IF O3MAX < 0.070 THEN Category = "Moderate";
    ELSE IF O3MAX < 0.085 THEN Category = "UnhealthySensitive";
    ELSE IF O3MAX < 0.105 THEN Category = "Unhealthy";
    ELSE IF O3MAX < 0.200 THEN Category = "VeryUnhealthy";
    ELSE Category = "Dangerous";
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA = WORK.POLLUTION;
TITLE= "O3";
RUN;
```

Comment: Why did you read Category when it will be overwritten anyway. Then you read Category as Nuumeric but write text into it.

Comment: What data are you trying to use?  To use INPUT you need either an INFILE statement or in-line data.  Or perhaps you have the data in a dataset already in which case eliminate the INPUT statement and add a SET statement instead.

Comment: Many thanks! SET statement is what it was missing!

Comment: You either have SET or an INPUT statement, it's very rare at this stage to need both.

Answer (score 1):

The `input` statement tells SAS how to read from a text file, but it does not specify where to look for the tekst. That you do with an `infile` statement, like in

```
DATA WORK.POLLUTION;
    INFILE "C:\myFolder\myInput.txt";
    INPUT State $ County $ City $ Month $ Year $ O3MAX $ Category;
    ...;
run;
```

Optionally you can give the information on the file upfront by giving it a name and referring it:

```
filename MY_TEXT "C:\myFolder\myInput.txt";

DATA WORK.POLLUTION;
    INFILE MY_TEXT;
    INPUT State $ County $ City $ Month $ Year $ O3MAX $ Category;
    ...;
run;
```

A special filename is `datalines`, which refers to inline data, between a `datalines` statement and a semicolon

```
DATA WORK.POLLUTION;
    INFILE datalines;
    INPUT State $ County $ City $ Month $ Year $ O3MAX $ Category;
    ...;
datalines; 
<your data comes here>
;
run;
```

If you don't specify an INFILE statement `infile datalines;` is implicitly used, but as you don't give a `datalines;` statement, there is no input. I bet your log tells something about zero lines read.

By the way, why do you specify Category in the `input` statement? I suppose it is only in your output.

There is a lot more to say about the `infile` statement. You have for instance options to handle lines with not all data filled in, like `trunkover`, which you should read about.